# In Ruby on Rails, what if a view needs to use jQuery that is loaded at the end of application layout?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

One recommended practice is to load jQuery at the end of application layout:

```
= yield

= render 'shared/footer'

= javascript_include_tag 'jquery'
```

so that page rendering is faster without the hinderance of Javascript or jQuery.  But what if there are some particular things that each view needs to do?  For example, the `index` view need to do something, and the `show` view needs to do something else, and so the Javascript code would either be inside those view templates or be included from those view templates, but at this point, the `jquery.js` file is not loaded yet (not until near the end of page)?  The `jquery.js` can be loaded before the `yield`, but then it is way in front of the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your could use the content_for

In layout

```
yield
render 'footer'
javascript_include_tag 'jquery'
yield :custom_javascript
```

In views

```
<%= content_for :custom_javascript do %>
<script type="text/javascript">alert(jQuery)</script>
<% end %
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-content_for

Comment: I agree with all of this except I think a better example would be to include section specific javascript files, rather than have inline js.

Comment: @brad depending on the extent i totally agree

Answer (score 1):

Fonsan is right. Plus remember to check your dom is loadedwhen you use jQuery.

So wrap it this way:

```
$(function(){
   // your js code here
});
```